# Does a service layer act as a facade for the DAL?

Tags: c#, oop, repository, service-layer

I am reading up about service layers and repositories. Now I am wondering if a service layer must wrap the dal. I am working a lot with repositories and the MVP pattern. The presenters now holds the business logic. But the more I think about it, it is not a logic place to put the business logic in the presenter nor the data access layer. So this is the point the service layer comes in.

But does the presenter now talks to the service layer? And is it 'allowed' that the presenter can access the repositories? Or should everything go via the service layer? In the latter case, the service layer is just a middleman:

MyFooService:

```
public List<Foo> GetAllFoo()
{
   var listFoo = new FooRepository().GetAll().TiList();

   return listFoo;
}
```

Presenter:

```
public List<Foo> GetAllFoo()
{
   var listFoo = new MyFooService().GetAllFoo();

   return listFoo;
}
```

Is the good way to go? Or is it 'allowed' that the presenter directly calls the repository?

Comment: You need to also be clear on what you mean by business logic, what kinda business logic does the presenter contain?

Comment: @gideon It contains some logic that must be reused by webservices

Comment: Not sure I get you, if your presenter is **calling/using** web services, this is not business logic, if your presenter/controller is doing things that need to **be reused** then this needs to be put into a class. Business logic is stuff that you do through an interface, like `Add(a,b)`, addition is business logic, but calling `MathService.Add(a,b)` and then giving this output to the presentation is NOT business logic, its controller logic.

Comment: @gideon What I mean is that at this moment I put business logic (may an object change from status) in the presenter (in your case the controller). Now I have to create webservices, which also needs this business logic. But the webservice cannot access the presenter, so I need to create a service layer, right?

Comment: Yes, you encapsulate the logic that needs to be re-used into classes and this could be your service layer, and then use it accordingly in both your presenter and webservice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes you do not need to over engineer things or force into patterns when you don't need them.

The DAL, is itself sorta a special service to access data.

Typically your service layer will do stuff not related directly to your data. Think things like *PaymentService*, *AnalyticsService* etc  things like that, that can be separated into a re-usable component.

Lets say you needed to share a post on to all social media, you *could* put this into a service that does the job of signing into the right social media and posting:

```
MySocialBlastService : ISocialService 
{
  void ShareToTwitter() {  }
  void ShareToFacebook(){ }
}
```

Now from your controller/presenter you can call this service.

```
public ActionResult ShareLink(string link..) //asp.net-mvc method as an example
{// maybe you could use dependency injection here to get ISocialService
  ISocialService _service;
  _service.ShareToTwitter(link);
}
```

---

Just so you're clear on what business logic is:

```
MathService
{
 int Add(a,b) { ..} //this is business logic
}
```

Its some stuff you need to do, and you can do it without touching an interface, this needs to be encapsulated. More real world examples are `SecurityService.ResetPassword()`

When you call this from the controller:

You could use the business logic of *adding*  in a web app, or in a windows app, and get the inputs from the user through some interface. *How* you do that is controller logic.

```
public ActionResult Calculate(int a, int b)//comes from webpage
{
 //this is controller logic
 int ret = MathService.Add(a,b);
 //logic to send ret back 
 //to some other page to display to user.
}
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly, it is okay for the presenter to invoke the repositories..

Comment: Yes the presenter/controller can call the service and the data layer.  This is IMO a slightly complex definition but it might help (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). Updated my answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you are doing "serious" middle to big scale development it is better not to put business logic into your presentation layer. How you isolate it is another question.

On the other side if you use something like Entity Framework or NHibernate I would only create repositories if it is really necessary to abstract data access, for using mocks when testing, for example.